# Event order jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've a HTML aside element on my page and I've appended the element some effects (animating). I'm almost done, but I cannot figured it out why the animations for some reason executes disordered...please concentrate on the second function if it is possible because I don't want to mess up a code that works perfectly

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("aside, #top").hover(function(){
    $("aside").animate({width:100}, 700);
    $("#top").animate({width:100}, 700);
    $("#navigation").show();
});

$("aside, #top").mouseleave(function(){
    $("aside").animate({width:10}, 700);
    $("#top").animate({width:10}, 700);
    $("#navigation").hide();
});
```

The last one

```
$("#navigation").hide();
```

Is executed before the other two in the same function. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason hide is executed 'first' is that all three are being executed at the same time. To order animations you need to use callbacks or chaining. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

The callback will run after the animation has finished. It only appears to run first because `.hide` takes no time at all, but the animations take `700ms` to run.

You could also use a timeout if you want the `.hide` to occur at a specific point in the animation cycle.

```
$("aside, #top").mouseleave(function(){
    $("aside").animate({width:10}, 700);
    $("#top").animate({width:10}, 700, function(){
         $("#navigation").hide();
    });        
});
```

or

```
$("aside, #top").mouseleave(function(){
    $("aside").animate({width:10}, 700);
    $("#top").animate({width:10}, 700);
    setTimeout(function(){
         $("#navigation").hide();
    }, 700);        
});
```

---

(psst. "Append" means something closer to concatenate, you don't append effects to elements, you attach them. And animation operations are not events, so its not an event order problem, its an execution order problem. Cheers.)

Comment: Yes it is. The appearance of 'firstness' is a perception thing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback:

```
$("#top").animate({width:10}, 700, function(){
    $("#navigation").hide();
});
```

Regarding to why, An easy explanation: it's because the first two lines takes time to finish while the last runs and finish right away, before those two finished.

Comment: Your explanation on the other hand is not correct, all three run right away. 2 just take longer to finish.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, Yes as I wrote... ?!

Comment: It's a good answer but, when I say .hide(1000), I must wait the execution of the .hide first, and then the .animate starts.

Comment: @Nino. I didn't get your comment.

Comment: Can you please paste me the whole function, because it's a little bit weird for me. I don't use jQuery often. Thanks!

Comment: Nope, It's my fault! forget it...can you just write/paste me the second part of the script, then I'll get it! Thank you again!